# Unity Loading Sprites with Addressables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am very new to Unity and after doing some research I found a lot of discussion on how I shouldn't use Resources.Load and instead use Addressables.

Previously I was loading card art with

```
cardPrefab.cardArt.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("CardSprite/Justice");
```

However I can't seem to get Addressable to work. Trying the following gives me an error:

```
 Sprite Test = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite>("CardSprite_Justice");
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationHandle<UnityEngine.Sprite>' to 'UnityEngine.Sprite'
```

Which is really confusing.

Comment: LoadAssetAsync is "Async" so you have to wait that , try use LoadAsset ?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.7/manual/AddressableAssetsAsyncOperationHandle.html

Comment: LoadAsset gives the same error + this one - 'Addressables.LoadAsset<TObject>(object)' is obsolete

Answer (score 2):

Get it with callback

```
private void Sprite_Completed(AsyncOperationHandle<Sprite> handle)
{
    if (handle.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
    {
        Sprite result = handle.Result;
        // Sprite ready for use
    }
}

void Start()
{
    AsyncOperationHandle<Sprite> SpriteHandle = Addressables.LoadAsset<Sprite>("CardSprite_Justice");
    SpriteHandle.Completed += Sprite_Completed;
}
```

and you can use coroutines or task to get it , watch document : 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.7/manual/AddressableAssetsAsyncOperationHandle.html

Answer (score 0):

```
void Start()
{     
       Addressables.LoadResourceLocationsAsync("SpriteName",typeof(Sprite)).Completed += SpriteLocation;

}

 void SpriteLocation(AsyncOperationHandle<IResourceLocation> obj)
    {  
      Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite>(_spriteName).Completed += obj => item.mysprite.sprite = obj.Result;

   }
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!